# Disable interaction for a certain component using UIPickerView

Tags: ios, components, uipickerview

I have an `UIPickerView` with 4 columns/components.

I want the other 3 components to be either disabled or so that they cannot accept interactions from users while one of the components is spinning.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish that? Thanks.

edited: add sample code, something like below:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSInteger rs1 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSInteger rs2 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
    NSInteger rs3 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2];
    NSInteger rs4 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:3];

    NSLog(@"selected: %d %d %d %d",rs1, rs2, rs3, rs4);        
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 4;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return 10;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UIImageView *slotImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    if (component == 0) {
        [slotImage setImage:...];
    }else if (component == 1) {
        [slotImage setImage:...];
    }else if (component == 2) {
        [slotImage setImage:...];
    }else if (component == 3) {
        [slotImage setImage:...];
    }        
    return slotImage;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you already have?